# add_editor_style not working after upgrade to WP v 6.2

Tags: updates, add-editor-style

I had a site I was running with a block-based/FSE theme on WP v.6.1.1. In `functions.php`, I was loading my theme stylesheet in the Gutenberg editor using the following:

```
function dnl_theme_add_editor_styles() {
  add_editor_style();
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'dnl_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

This worked perfectly well (`editor-style.css` loaded in Gutenberg) until I upgraded to WordPress 6.2. After that, the stylesheet stopped getting loaded in the editor. I tried loading `style.css` using `add_editor_style` like so:

```
function dnl_theme_add_editor_styles() {
  add_editor_style( 'style.css' );
}
```

I also tried calling `add_theme_support` first, e.g.:

```
function dnl_theme_add_editor_styles() {
  add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );
  add_editor_style();
}
```

But none of that helped.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior after upgrading? Does anyone know why this would be happening? I looked at the source code for `add_editor_style` in `wp-includes/theme.php` and didn't see any changes there since 6.1.1.

Comment: Does your theme use `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' )`?

Comment: I wasn't using that. I tried adding that line just now, but it didn't help (I tried adding it before the `add_action` call, as well as within the function `dnl_theme_add_editor_styles` called by the `add_action` call copied above, with and without `add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' )`). No combination seemed to have any effect; the theme styles still aren't loading in Gutenberg.

Comment: all styles? Or just styles that reference files and assets? Are you using css container queries?

Comment: @TomJNowell, in my case I am just trying to load the style.css file located at the theme root in Gutenberg. I have also tried to get it to load editor-style.css at the theme root, which WP docs say should happen if you pass no arguments to add_editor_style. I am using container queries.

Comment: I see, in my own project we've found container queries broke editor styles, and have had to have a separate place for container queries so that we can load the rest into both

Comment: @TomJNowell, just tried removing the container queries and this worked as expected. Very odd, but glad it worked.

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/49862

Answer (score 1):

**UDATE**

Following @TomJNowell's comments, I tried removing container queries from my stylesheets, and as `add_editor_style` worked as expected. This seems like a bug to me, though there may be a logical explanation for this I am not aware of. In my case, I think I would prefer to keep using container queries, so I will probably be sticking to my JS solution below, but I figured it was worth flagging.

**Previous answer**

In lieu of an actual fix to `add_editor_style`, I have the following partial workaround/hack in place for now, in case it is helpful for others with this problem:

In functions.php:

```php
function dnl_load_theme_styles_in_gutenberg() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'gutenberg-styles.js',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/gutenberg-styles.js',
  );
}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'dnl_load_theme_styles_in_gutenberg' );
```

In `gutenberg-styles.js`:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const themeStyleTag = document.createElement('link');

  themeStyleTag.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
  themeStyleTag.setAttribute('href', `/wp-content/themes/my-theme-name/style.css?v=${new Date().getTime()}`);

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(themeStyleTag);
});
```

Assuming the CSS you want to load into Gutenberg is called `style.css` and is located in your theme root, and you swap out `my-theme-name` with the name of your theme, this should work.

I should note one important difference between doing this and using `add_editor_style`: the latter prefaces all your CSS file's selectors with `.editor-styles-wrapper`, whereas the former does not. So, if your theme CSS includes, e.g.

```css
.my-custom-block {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: hotpink;
}
```

And you inject your theme CSS into Gutenberg with `add_editor_style`, Gutenberg will inline the following CSS in the editor view:

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper .my-custom-block {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: hotpink;
}
```

...changing the specificity of the selector.

Whereas my JS-based hack will just add the same CSS block you had in your theme CSS, since all it does is load the theme CSS into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can happen also when there's **syntax error in the CSS**. On frontend the browser can ignore the error (like missing `}`) but the editor cannot parse it.